# BASH Script: BTEQ Command Issue

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, teradata

I am learning shell scripting and I'm experiencing an odd issue.
When I attempt to connect to a Teradata database using BTEQ I am able to log in and run the query, but with each step (IE .LOGON, .QUIT, .EXIT, etc...) the screen shows information about the database and displays the name of the 2 files I have in my home directory.

I've highlighted a command (.LOGOFF) in green to demonstrate and I've highlighted the names of the files in yellow.  Every thing else is additional information that I don't want either.  I only want the results of the query.

[image: This is what is output to the screen]

Here is the script that I'm using. (Be gentle, it's my first script outside of the manuals.)
[image]

I've done a few dozen searches, but I can't find anything dealing with the issue I am experiencing.  Thank you for any help you can offer.

Comment: Because the shell by default performs word splitting and pathname expansion on the `$(...)` result; among potentially other things that replaces each `*` with the list of filenames in the working directory. You can use double quotes to avoid that `"$(bteq...)"`

Comment: Please do not use images of text in questions.  Read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question